# How to avoid typing password

Tags: sql, postgresql

My current system is Ubuntu 18.04

I installed PostgreSQL.

When I run the following command: `psql -U node_user dummydb` I get the following message: `psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "node_user"`

I currently have to access the database using this command: `psql -U node_user -h localhost dummydb` which works. However, It's quite tedious to enter `-h localhost` in every time I want to access the database.

The database is on my local machine, and only for learning purposes

Is there a way to run `psql -U node_user dummydb` without `-h localhost` and also without entering password?

Comment: You can define [an environment variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html)  `PGHOST` that is picked up by psql.

Comment: also did you try . (dot) instead of localhost

Answer (score 0):

You can make an alias in your .bashrc or .bash_aliases file. Simply add the following line:

myalias="psql --host= --dbname= --port=5432 --user="

Run source ~/.bashrc

Then you can simply run myalias and type in the password at the prompt, or use .pgpass to save typing in your password